# Compiling SQLite into programs that run on Symbian 9.1 and above?

Tags: sqlite, symbian

How can I use SQLite C API’s on any device running Symbian OS 9.1 or above? While it appears that 9.4 comes with SQLite built in prior versions do not. Looking at http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlites60/ it appears that sQLite has been ported to older Symbian releases. The only problem is this code assumes you want to use SQLite with .net when I want to compile it into a .sis file and call the C API’s. Ideally I’d compile a Symbian equivalent of amalgamation.c and call the sQLite functions directly but am not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The sqlite port you linked to seems usable using the C API - there's `sqlite.dll` exporting the C API and `System.Data.SQLiteClient.dll exposing the .net API. It's also based on sqlite 3.5.4 which is not the most recent version. Some functionality of more recent versions may not be available.

Symbian OS 9.4 SQLite only has a custom client-server interface (`RSqlDatabase` and such) and does not expose the native C API. The C API is available from Symbian OS 9.5 onwards.